# AIR: securityError on OSX (but not on Windows) with URLStream()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, sandbox

I'm using URLStream to load a file from the harddisk (and I'd like to continue to use URLStream to do so). The file is located in "app-storage:/myfolder/myFile.zip"

so I use

```
var f:File = new File("app-storage:/myfolder/myFile.zip");
myStream.load(new URLRequest(f.nativePath));
```

on Windows this seems to work without problems - but on OS X the URLStream dispatches a SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR with the message:

```
Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/Users/myUserName/Library/Preferences/MyAppName/Local%20Store/myfolder/myFile.zip
```

can someone explain me why this works on windows but not on OS X and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Good old, ambiguous error 2032!

You might want to try:

```
var f:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory + "/myFolder/myFile.zip");
```

**EDIT**

My original comment was to use the `File.applicationStorageDirectory` property, and I still think that's a good idea. But it looks like that property boils down to the same string that you are using ... so perhaps the problem is that the location of the storage dir has changed and the file you are looking for is still in the original location? See link below.

**End Edit**

Note the [comment here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory) about a change made to this path in Air 3.3 for Mac OSX only. Even if this doesn't fix your problem, using this property should shield your code from future problems if the path changes or a different "schema" is needed for some other device/OS.

Comment: no - the path was correct - somehow i think AIR on OS X does not use the application security sandbox if an absolute path is used even if this absolute path points to the app-storage directory. I changed now f.nativePath to f.url which now works on both, Windows and OS X. Still - if someone has a proper explanation for this, would be apreciated.